# Unable to Turn-Off STRICT STANDARDS in WAMP

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I'm hopelessly trying to turn off **STRICT STANDARDS** wanrings in **WAMP** but it seems that nothing works! 
I've set `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` in the following files:

- `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini`
- `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\phpForApache.ini`
- `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini`

I've also set `$phpConf['phpConfFile'] = 'php.ini';` in `wampserver.conf`.

`phpinfo()` says *'Loaded Configuration File'* is `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini` while `php -i` says it's `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini`! Although both agree on `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows`! But there's no such file in the whole windows directory and its subfolders!

I'm deperate! I neighter have time to install another Package and nor have clearance to change the code and fix STRICT STANDARDS.

> EDIT: I forgot to mention that it was working fine until this morning when I had a system reset.

Comment: Why not fix the code?

Comment: It is an organizational framework with thousands of such error and tens of thousands of code line

Comment: Try to put php.ini into Windows directory : )

Comment: @sectus: just did it.. no change! I think this is something kept in memory, not on file. But where and how? :(

Comment: @sectus: I restart apache even after slightest changes... following your suggestion, I stopped all the services - closed WAMP - opened it again and started services again: no luck...

Comment: Are you sure that it's not your application settings?

Comment: @sectus: If you mean the application I'm working on, yes I'm sure. Because otherwise it wouldn't have worked the previous 3 month :)
But if you mean WAMP, i'm not aware of any menu or section which keeps such settings?

Comment: @sectus: There's just one .htaccess in my www which contains application values only and doesn't seem to have anything to do with apache settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdest of all, I finally found out the problem: mysql crash had resulted in corruption of some core tables in my application's framework. Using the beloved `phpMyAdmin`, I repaired these tables (while trying to dump all my databases) and that was it! Suddenly all errors on `STRICT STANDARDS` were shut down!
As weird as this may be, It works as a perfect solution. Just try to dump your databases to find out if any tables are corrupted and then repair them. Although my problem is fixed, I'm still wondering how corrupted mysql tables could result in `STRICT STANDARDS` to not turn off!
So This is The Scenario:

1. System Crash Resulted in `STRICT STANDARDS` to Show Up and It Wasn't Possible to Turn Them Off!
2. I Decided to Change the Whole WAMP thing to XAMPP. So, First Step Was to Dump All My Databases.
3. While Trying to Use `mysqldump`, I Found Out Some Tables Were Corrupted During the System Failure.
4. I Used `phpMyAdmin` (`REPAIR TABLE` command) to Fix These Tables and to Continue the Dump.
5. Surprisingly, After Repairing the Tables, I Accidentally Found Out that My Application is Workin Just Fine! i.e. No More STRICT STANDARDS Errors (I Didn't Even Restart Apache!)
6. Anyhow, I'm Migrating to XAMPP for having better support and a wider community.